# Getting different req.url in express-node when calling with proxy setup

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, proxy

I am making ajax call to node server, i have a set of my request like this in front-end

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/getdata/call',
   dataType: 'json',
   method: 'get',
   contentType: 'application/json'
   ....
});
```

when I print the `request url` parameter in node server using express i got like this

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
     console.log(req.url); // /getdata/call
     next();
});
```

and everything is working fine, and i set a proxy in by browser settings with manual proxy configuration.

after that I am getting the request url like

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
         console.log(req.url); // http:192.168.192.10/getdata/call
         next();
});
```

ie, the full path of the request server , and because of that i cant resolve the request properly, i need an relative path for `req.url` always like `'/getdata/**'`

i tried to replace it like ,

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
     req.url = req.url.replace('wht is the ip','');
     next();
});
```

but req object is setting that in other props like `originalUrl`, and in some request path modifying the url is giving 404.

**So is there any way to set the url in request header** or  **proxy settings header** etc. ? 
ajax header `'location, host'` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `req.path` instead of `req.url`.